# sed replace with a really long file content

Tags: sed

so i have a file with a string and i would like to replace that with the content of another file (or output from another command). the problem is that it's long and it will fail. it works fine when the it's short though.

the command i use is like this

```bsh
sed -i "s#\(var wasm = \)\".*\";#\\1\"`cat dist/camaro.wasm | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02X"'`\";#" dist/camaro.js
```

when the `camaro.wasm` file is small, it works. however, if it's big, the command will fail with error  `argument list too long: sed`

how would i go about fixing this?

update:

camaro.js content

```
var camaro = (function() {
    "use strict";

    var wasm = "testtest";

})();
```

camaro.wasm content can be anything. any text fine would be fine. i would like to replace `testtest` with content of `camaro.wasm` file or another command

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind editing your question to include an extract of the `camaro.js` and `camaro.wasm` file so that we better understand what structure you are trying to replace, and what in general the replacement text will look like?

Comment: @AdminBee added.

Comment: Given that `"testtest"` is quoted, can you say that the included file (or command output) is only one line? If not, how would you like the result to look?

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? "if it's big" – what file size are we talking about here? There may be interla `sed` limits. In any case the command line cannot exceed 128K.

Comment: What should happen if the file you insert contains quotes?

Comment: @seshoumara it's safe, because i hexdump it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging what should i do in this case? is there alternative? btw, it's ~ 200K big

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of inserting the hexdump into an `s` replacement string, try reading as a file:

```bsh
{ printf '    %s' 'var wasm = "'; hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02X"' camaro.wasm; } |

sed -e '/var wasm = ".*";/ {' -e 'r /dev/stdin' -e 'a\";' -e 'd;}' camaro.js
```

output:

```
var camaro = (function() {
    "use strict";

    var wasm = "6C645950577A62776A57696452624E43... etc.";

})();
```

---

- Note: The above replaces the entire line matching `var wasm = ".*";` with the contents of stdin + `";` – it's not a general alternative to `s/match/replacement/`. Also, it only works correctly for the first matching line – any subsequent matching lines are replaced with `";`. Consider using `awk` or `perl` if you need to solve these problems.

---

To use a long string as part of a `sed` script, pass the editing commands to `sed` as a script file:

```
sed -f /dev/stdin camaro.js <<EOS
    s#\(var wasm = "\).*";#\1$(hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02X"' camaro.wasm)";#
EOS
```

- The potentially long string from `hexdump` generated in the command substitution is passed as a string, along with the rest of the `s` editing command, to the standard input of `sed`; `-f /dev/stdin` asks sed to use stdin as a script file, avoiding the "Argument list too long" error

Comment: It works. Many thanks!

Comment: @TuanAnhTran Glad to help. Just thought of using a script file to solve this issue – added it to the answer.